# Can not add string to the video using ffmpeg base on PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm new in ffmpeg and I'm trying to make a demo using ffmpeg.
Below is the PHP script

```
$cmd = '"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i C:\wamp\www\vine-project\cron/tmp/t_42953497622724.mp4 --enable-libfreetype -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C:\wamp\www\demo-ffmpeg\cron/arial.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor='Black':fontsize=19" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy C:\wamp\www\demo-ffmpeg\cron/tmp/text_42953497622724.mp4';
@exec($cmd, $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

And then below is the result of output:

```
Array
(
)
```

Before, I joined multi videos and add background successfully.
Input video file is exists.
What is my wrong? Are something incorrect?
3 cups of beer for each help :D 
Sorry for my bad English

Thanks for attention!

Comment: `--enable-libfreetype` is an argument passed while configuring ffmpeg for compilation. It's not meant for runtime use. Other than that, the command looks ok except for the mixed use of slashes \ and / in the paths. Try using only backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanh Dao**
   You can use this, it works for me.

**"ffmpeg -i C:\wamp\www\vine-project\cron/tmp/t_42953497622724.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontfile='C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf':text=\"Stack Overflow\":fontsize=30:fontcolor=yellow -y C:\wamp\www\demo-ffmpeg\cron/tmp/text_42953497622724.mp4 2>&1"**

After a long search, I made it and in the way, I reached to your post.

It works for me shine and bright. This FFmpeg has so many complications, with this query. But with a little adjustment, you can achieve what you want. Hope this will work for you.